# Clear token in Facebook SDK V4.0.1 for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook Login version 4.0.1 for iOS, and I would like to clear session/ token programatically when I logout of my application. But I am unable to do so. I am importing

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

but still I am unable to find a solution. In the previous version we could clear the token from FBSession. But in the new version I am unable to get the FBSession. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having? Be specific.

Comment: I am using Facebook as a login method for my app.But I am unable to logout of Facebook using my application.

Comment: But why can't you? Do you not know how? Are you getting a compiler error? Does your app crash? Or does your app simply not work as expected? As I said, be specific. Simply saying you are unable is the opposite of being specific. Update your question with relevant details about your issue.

Comment: I don't know how to logout. In the previous version we could clear the token from FBSession. But in the new version I am unable to get the FBSession.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the changelog for the FB SDK it states that `FBSession and FBAccessTokenData are replaced by FBSDKLoginManager`.

If you then take a look at `FBSDKLoginManager`, [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/), it states that

> FBSDKLoginManager provides methods for logging the user in and out.

Via this method you should be able to log the user out. Does the login button not automatically change to a logout button when the user is logged in?

Comment: The method is `logout`

Comment: i tried this but doesnot works :  var accesstoken: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        accesstoken.logOut()

Comment: no sorry..i figured it out later..that user is not completely logged out from the app...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092610/facebook-logout-is-not-working-in-new-sdk-v-4-1-0-in-ios/30093967?noredirect=1#comment48304924_30093967