# How to clear the credentials of facebook in ios application, when i hit on back to app button on the top in safari browser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I tried doing `[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];` `[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];` even after doing this and after running the application, I entered different credential to login to Facebook app, but it is still taking the previously entered credentials. So my question is how to clear or delete the credentials. Please someone help me in doing this. Thanks in advance for spending your time to go through this question and answering.

Comment: you can use code formatting to highlight the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions/"
   parameters:nil
   HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id  result, NSError *error) {
  // ...
 }];
```

there after add your facebook login code

for additional information [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092610/facebook-logout-is-not-working-in-new-sdk-v-4-1-0-in-ios)

or choice -2

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

if ( [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] ){
    [login logOut];
     [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
    [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be because it took the cookies from the Safari browser.

Go to your Xcode --> Product --> clean --> and run it

or

Uninstall the app and go to Safari browser in your iPhone, hit the facebook.com if it's already signed in, hit log out, then run your application.

Comment: if I run in device how do we handle this scenario

Comment: Bro am saying it in device only, go to safari browser in your device and do the else part that i have posted above.