# Unable to logout from Facebook after sign in swift2.0

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication, logout, let

I am not able to switch between Facebook login/logout.

I had logged in with `xyz@gmail.com` but when I am trying to login again then it is taking old user login credential for login . even I deleted the app from iPhone them also  it is taking old user credential which I used the first time .

I am using latest Facebook framework **FBSDKCoreKit.framework FBSDKLoginKit.framework FBSDKShareKit.framework**

i used this code for logout

```
let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.logOut()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092610/facebook-logout-is-not-working-in-new-sdk-v-4-1-0-in-ios

Comment: You are using latest `FBSDK`?

Comment: it got solved with changing other Facebook SDK , here it was https://github.com/tejas123/facebook-integration-using-swift/tree/master/FBIntegrationWithSwift